# Impossible to close reject modal dialog

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, suggested-edits

I noticed today that it is impossible to close the "rejection" modal dialog in review using the `X` or `cancel` link. Clicking the background outside the dialog still works.

When I click the links, the `Approve`, `Reject`, `Improve` and `Skip` buttons reappears, but the modal dialog won't disappear. I am using Chrome 25 on Mac 10.8.2.

[image]

Comment: Reproduced on Chrome on Mac. `ESC` still works too.

Comment: On Chrome and IE on Windows Vista too.

Comment: I'm having the same issue in FF19 on Windows 7.

Comment: From the comments, I think we can conclude that this is a site issue, not a browser issue. I did some tests and I concluded that the event attached on that cross is never executed. It looks like we can't select the correct element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The next deploy will fix this, which should be shortly.

Minor refactor of popup closing missed an edge case here where the rejection dialog hides itself rather than using common code.  Oddly enough, for the most part the popup is "gone" when the X is clicked; it's not really functionally correct anymore (it probably quacks correctly enough to still be used... but probably with errors).

Comment: and... [it's back](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244809/closing-edit-review-window-doesnt-close-reject-dialog)