# Closing edit review window doesn't close reject dialog

Tags: bug, edits, user-interface

[image: Edit review window]

Click the parent window's x:

[image: Reject window remains]

Oh noes, the child is left an orphan!

Comment: Looks like the fix for [this bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170936/impossible-to-close-reject-modal-dialog?rq=1) was overwritten. (by mistake, hopefully)

Comment: Meh. Why would you do this anyways? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: @JanDvorak Eh. Because I felt like it. Close it.

Comment: Work-around: hit ESC.